# Filter data by column K in Google Script Editor (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets-api

In this example, I have a set of data from a Google Sheet (4Cat) feeding into another sheet (ImportFeeder) where I am running my Google Script.

At the end of the script below, how can I insert a filter script to sort the data by Row K? (only showing iPad products)

[image]

```
function myFunction() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kL96dRm3Z8XBtMXnSzUARxR1b34-njlkZQ1sU0c3g1s'); //replace with source ID
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('4cat'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
var range = ss.getRange('A:I'); //assign the range you want to copy
var data = range.getValues();

var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1u7547KaniKHLUJn2v-ezN4l8ZcxE4viCFcoxsA904MI'); //replace with destination ID
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

var range = ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet 2
var data = []                       // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length ; i++){
if(rawData[i][10] == "iPad")            // Check to see if column K says ipad if not skip it
{
data.push(rawData[i])
}
}
}
```

(Cannot read property length from undefined)

4Cat Sample Data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kL96dRm3Z8XBtMXnSzUARxR1b34-njlkZQ1sU0c3g1s/edit?usp=sharing */

*feeding into*

ImportFeeder https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u7547KaniKHLUJn2v-ezN4l8ZcxE4viCFcoxsA904MI/edit?usp=sharing

**Required** - Successful sheet to sheet import, filter data by Row K within Google Scripts. Add a clear() sheet function to the top of the script, as this will be running daily and the sheet needing clearing before daily import.

Comment: You want to filter or sort? Filter remove everything except a particular value or sort alphabetically?

Comment: It's the filter I need via Google script, not sorting

Comment: Do you want to only copy a specific subset of data from the first spreadsheet to the second spreadsheet (ones with iPad in the column k)?

Comment: Thanks Jack. No the whole set of data comes over into the feeder sheet. Then the whole sheet is sorted by Column K, to display iPad products only

Comment: I added an edit towards how the final code should look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the documentation on [sorting in a range here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)). To sort select a range using getRange and then sort function like so

```
var range = ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
// Use the below line instead, if you want to sort whole sheet, not just the newly entered data! 
// var range = ts.getDataRange()     
range.sort(11)         // sort based on column number 11
```

**Edit 1:**
To filter only values based on the column to copy into the new sheet you will do need to trim the data you get from a sheet of all values you don't need.

```
var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet1
var data = []                       // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length ; i++){
 if(rawData[i][10] == "iPAD")            // Check to see if column K says ipad if not skip it
 {
 data.push(rawData[i])
 }
}
// Now you can paste array data to your new spreadsheet like before.
```

**Edit 2**: This how the final code should look like,

```
function myFunction() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kL96dRm3Z8XBtMXnSzUARxR1b34-njlkZQ1sU0c3g1s'); //replace with source ID
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('4cat'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
var range = ss.getRange('A:V');      //assign the range you want to copy
var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet 1
var data = []                       // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length ; i++){
if(rawData[i][10] == "iPad")            // Check to see if column K says ipad if not skip it
{
data.push(rawData[i])
}
}
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1u7547KaniKHLUJn2v-ezN4l8ZcxE4viCFcoxsA904MI'); //replace with destination ID
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

Comment: Get this error with edit 2, --------- TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 15, file "Code")

Comment: Which line is exactly no: "15"

Comment: Also try changing the this line `if(rawData[i][10] == "iPAD") ` to `if(rawData[i][10] == "iPad") ` note the change in capital to small letters

Comment: OK, thats importing now, so almost there. But everything after row J hasn't imported or the filter kicked in [Results]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u7547KaniKHLUJn2v-ezN4l8ZcxE4viCFcoxsA904MI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Modified the above code, to include range ("A:V"), that should take care of it

Comment: Just tried running modified code again, last line "15" getting flagged again ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); with TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 15, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: Sorry,  my bad the  the for loop was not closed. I fixed it, please try now.

Comment: You beauty, that's done it. Ticked. many thanks for your work.

Answer (score 8):

Why not using a custom filter function?
Added a `.toLowerCase()` to match "ipad" case insensitive.

```
function myFunction() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kL96dRm3Z8XBtMXnSzUARxR1b34-njlkZQ1sU0c3g1s'); //replace with source ID
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('4cat');   //replace with source Sheet tab name
var range = ss.getRange('A:V');        //assign the range you want to copy
var rawData = range.getValues()        // get value from spreadsheet 1
var data = rawData.filter(isColKiPad); // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1u7547KaniKHLUJn2v-ezN4l8ZcxE4viCFcoxsA904MI'); //replace with destination ID
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(2,1,ts.getLastRow() - 1,ts.getLastColumn()).clear(); // Assuming header is in the first row, clears sheet but header
ts.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
};
// Change both to ts.getRange(1,1,[...] if there's no header row
function isColKiPad(arr) {
  return arr[10].toLowerCase() == "ipad";
};
```

Did you consider using a Spreadsheet formula? You could try a combination of `=IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, string_range)` and `QUERY(data, query, [header])` to import your range already filtered :

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1kL96dRm3Z8XBtMXnSzUARxR1b34-njlkZQ1sU0c3g1s";"4cat!A:V");"SELECT * WHERE Col11 = 'iPad'")
```

You won't even need to clear your sheet this way.

Answer (score 5):

you can add this to your original code:

```
filterByText(rawData, 10, iPad);
```

It will work as long as you add this function after your myFunction function:

```
function filterByText(data, columnIndex, values) {
    var value = values;
    if (data.length > 0) {
        if (typeof columnIndex != "number" || columnIndex > data[0].length) {
            throw "Please, can you choose a valid column index?";
        }
        var r = [];
        if (typeof value == "string") {
            var reg = new RegExp(escape(value).toUpperCase());
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (columnIndex < 0 && escape(data[i].toString()).toUpperCase().search(reg) != -1 || columnIndex >= 0 && escape(data[i][columnIndex].toString()).toUpperCase().search(reg) != -1) {
                    r.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
            return r;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
                    var reg = new RegExp(escape(value[j]).toUpperCase());
                    if (columnIndex < 0 && escape(data[i].toString()).toUpperCase().search(reg) != -1 || columnIndex >= 0 && escape(data[i][columnIndex].toString()).toUpperCase().search(reg) != -1) {
                        r.push(data[i]);
                        j = value.length;
                    }
                }
            }
            return r;
        }
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Above is the [code](https://sites.google.com/site/nnillixxsource/Notable/PivotChartsLib/ArrayLib/filterByText_js) used by Google Apps Script's ArrayLib library [filterByText method](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library). I literally just copied it and made the throw friendlier.

Your full code could look something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kL96dRm3Z8XBtMXnSzUARxR1b34-njlkZQ1sU0c3g1s'); //replace with source ID
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('4cat'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var range = ss.getRange('A:I'); //assign the range you want to copy
  var data = range.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1u7547KaniKHLUJn2v-ezN4l8ZcxE4viCFcoxsA904MI'); //replace with destination ID
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  var range = ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
  var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet 2
  var data = filterByText(rawData, 10, iPad); // rawData is now sorted.
  range.clear();

  var powerRange = ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);

  powerRange.setValues(data);
} 

function filterByText(data, columnIndex, values) {
    var value = values;
    if (data.length > 0) {
        if (typeof columnIndex != "number" || columnIndex > data[0].length) {
            throw "Please, can you choose a valid column index?";
        }
        var r = [];
        if (typeof value == "string") {
            var reg = new RegExp(escape(value).toUpperCase());
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (columnIndex < 0 && escape(data[i].toString()).toUpperCase().search(reg) != -1 || columnIndex >= 0 && escape(data[i][columnIndex].toString()).toUpperCase().search(reg) != -1) {
                    r.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
            return r;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
                    var reg = new RegExp(escape(value[j]).toUpperCase());
                    if (columnIndex < 0 && escape(data[i].toString()).toUpperCase().search(reg) != -1 || columnIndex >= 0 && escape(data[i][columnIndex].toString()).toUpperCase().search(reg) != -1) {
                        r.push(data[i]);
                        j = value.length;
                    }
                }
            }
            return r;
        }
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```